# Vue-router's router-link doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Could please some one explain me: why my breadcrumbs like:

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'blablalba'}"> Blablabla </router-link>
```

works well only on main page? When I try use it in children it push me on main paige every time?

exepmle:

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'mainPage'}"> Main page</router-link>
<router-link :to="{name: 'firstPage'}"> First children </router-link>
<router-link :to="{name: 'secondChildren'}"> Second children </router-link>
```

No matter which link you will push, all time you will be pushed to main page

Comment: What does the route definition object look like?

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean?
File, where I definition 'name', 'path' and etc for each component? Or how I definition vue router? I mean import 'Vue' and Vue.use(...)?

Comment: I mean somewhere you defined the routes, `var routes = [...]`. Can you show that?

Comment: Sorry for waiting.

`import { routes as app } from '../app'
Vue.use(Router);
const routes = [...app];
const router = new Router({
  routes,
  linkActiveClass: 'current',
  //mode: 'history', // do not use /#/.
});`

Comment: @Bert ,
routes is:
`import { routes as auth } from './auth'
import { routes as example } from './example'
export default [
  ...auth, ...example]`